# How to edit a QListwidgetItem by using custom context menu?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have a `QListWidget` named `xml_scripts_textbox` with some items in my UI, and when i right click on an item in my qlistwidget, a custom context menu appears, and one of the option of this context menu is `"Edit the List item"`, so when this is clicked , i want that particular item in qlistwidget to be editable for once,

How can i do this ?

The code i have tried so far is

context menu code

```
void MainWindow::on_xml_scripts_textbox_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint& pos)
{
    QMenu* rMenu = new QMenu(this);
    QAction* edit = new QAction(tr("Edit the List item"), this);

    rMenu->addAction(edit);
    connect(edit, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(edithelp()));
    rMenu->exec(cursor().pos());

}
```

code for `edithelp()`, the slot function which will make the listitem editable

```
void MainWindow::edithelp()
{
    QListWidgetItem* item_1 = ui->xml_scripts_textbox->takeItem(ui->xml_scripts_textbox->currentRow());
    item_1->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEditable);  // still not getting editable ?? why ??
}
```

Comment: I don't think QListiWidget::takeItem() is what you need. As the doc says QListiWidget::takeItem "Removes and returns the item from the given row in the list widget", so after that the item should no longer be inside the QListWidget. You should try QListiWidget::itemAt() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set item is editable?

```
item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void MainWindow::edithelp()
{
    QListWidgetItem* item_1 = ui->xml_scripts_textbox->currentItem();
    if (item_1)
        ui->xml_scripts_textbox->editItem(item_1);
}
```

Comment: currently i am doing it with the help of a dialog box like this `QListWidgetItem* item_1 = ui->xml_scripts_textbox->takeItem(ui->xml_scripts_textbox->currentRow());
    QString custom_line = QInputDialog::getText(this, "Edit Command", "\nEnter the change:\n", QLineEdit::Normal, item_1->text());
    item_1->setText(custom_line);
    ui->xml_scripts_textbox->addItem(item_1);`